# three.js snapshot from multiple cameras

Tags: three.js

I am looking for solution for take snapshoot from "hidden" camera not used in main canvas/viewport.

I am **not** looking for multiple viewports like this:
https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_multiple_views.html

I would like to have main canvas which is visible for user and he see view from main camera.But when he click "download" button, it would generate not current view but static view defined in script without changing any view for user.

I tried make this:

```
var camera2 = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( view1.fov, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
view1.camera = camera2;

var canvasPdfScene = document.createElement('canvas');
canvasPdfScene.id = 'canvasPdfScene';
canvasPdfScene.width = '2048';
canvasPdfScene.height = '512';
canvasPdfScene.style.borderBottom = '1px solid black';
//window.context = temCanvas.getContext('2d');
var pdfContext = canvasPdfScene.getContext('2d', {preserveDrawingBuffer: true});

var actualCanvas = renderer.domElement;

//document.body.appendChild(canvasPdfScene);
renderer.domElement = canvasPdfScene;

renderer.render( scene, camera2 );

renderer.domElement = actualCanvas;
```

Comment: You could potentially use a secondary render target (`THREE.WebGLRenderTarget`) and read the pixels from it, and draw those pixels onto a secondary `canvas`. I don't have time to spin up an example right now, but hopefully this will send you in a good direction.